# Using wget to download images directed by thumbnails

Tags: php, image, wget

I have the URL of a gallery. This gallery is structured like www.url.com/folder/image01.php

Here, www.url.com/folder shows the thumbnails, and clicking on each thumbnail redirects to the php page as mentioned.

I wish to download FULL size images, ie. the image from php page, rather than thumnails folder.

I use the following line: wget -r -L -A .jpg www.url.com/folder

However, this only downloads the thumbnails (each thumbnail points to a larger image, and i want to go to each of this image and download them, rather than the images in thumbnail directory)

I've been stuck with this problem for quite a while, is there a solution for this?

Comment: How is image01.php structured to redirect to the large one?  If you can display the source code then should be able to work out how to get it running.

Comment: url.com/folder/ shows some 20 thumbnails. clicking on a thumbnail directs to url.com/folder/image01.php, url.com/folder/image02.php, and so on for each of the 20 thumbnails. Now, I need to download  the actual bigger image, ie. image01 from the .php page, but the line that I execute downloads the thumbnails and terminates after it.

Comment: I think I understand - /folder/ contains a file that spits out mulitple IMG tags, each wrapped in an A tag?

Comment: Yes exactly! This A tag has the href as url.com/folder/image01.php. The img tag in each A tag has the properties of thumbnail defined (size, location; which is thumbs/image01.jpg) The line i execute downloads this thumbnail, instead of the one given by the A tag

Comment: I've just tried wget -r -l 1 - A jpeg,jpg,gif,png http://www.url.com/file.htm and it's pulled the thumbnail and linked file :)

Comment: Ok so I looked into it a little bit. Let the Gallery name be abc. The path for the image is url.com/some_folder/abc/abc_001.jpg. Can you give me the code through which I can download these images, all from 001 to 015?

Answer (score 0):

Not much experienced with wget but my understanding is that the command you are using will recursively download all .jpg files in the relative url's appearing in the provided web page.

It would help to know what web page you are trying to access and analyse how full sized images are accessed, but my guess is that only thumbnail images are directly accessible through relative links from the webpage.

You should probably check if any javascript is used to provide the access to the full size image. If so, wget will not be helpful since (as far as I am aware) it will only work on plain HTML text of the initial web page and is not capable of figuring out links created dynamically through Javascript.